# External script can't recognize model fields

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a script which I intend to use in a scheduled fashion.
This script is not part of the django project, but communicates with it.

The script stars like

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
from django.db.models import Q
from app.models import *

transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(Q(paypal_auth != None)
    and Q(paypal_auth.payer_id != None))
```

Now the problem is the output of the python console:

```
AttributeError: module 'app.models.paypal_auth' has no attribute 'payer_id'
```

So why is this happening?

**Thanks to @daniel, this is my solution:**

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(~Q(paypal_auth__payment_id=None)
    & ~Q(paypal_auth__payer_id=None))
```

Comment: Show us the code that sets `paypal_auth`.

Comment: What do you mean by sets?

Comment: Oops; I was confused.  Ignore that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with external scripts. That's not how you do queries in Django; there are several things wrong, and they'd be just as wrong in your main application.

You need to use the double-underscore syntax to cross relations; also, you can't use expressions like `!=`, nor can you use `and`. Your query should be:

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    Q(paypal_auth__ne=None) & Q(paypal_auth__payer_id__ne=None))
```

Although note that your second condition implies the first, so you could just do:

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.filterpaypal_auth__payer_id__ne=None)
```

Comment: Are sure that it is && and not &?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Of course even if you did want to keep the two queries, you don't need Q at all for AND; you could do `Transaction.objects.filter(paypal_auth__ne=None, paypal_auth__payer_id__ne=None)`

Answer (score 0):

You imported the `paypal_auth` module, but the class is `PayPalAuth`, which is presumably within the `paypal_auth` module.

Try `paypal_auth.PayPalAuth.payer_id` (or refer to a `payer_id` of a particular instance)

Comment: Using `Q(paypal_auth.PayPalAuth.payment_id != None)` returns `AttributeError: type object 'PayPalAuth' has no attribute 'payment_id'`